# Finding paths for packaged non-java files at runtime

Tags: java, web-applications, jboss, relative-path, directory-structure

So this might be a stupid question but...

I want to package a specific WSDL file in with an EJB project within eclipse. What would be the best way to refer to this file in my code?

I would like to use a relative path but the current directory starts off in the /bin directory of my JBOSS installation. It seems like there should be a way to refer to the file in relation to the project file structure.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getClass().getResource(String path)`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) uses a relative path to locate a classpath resource. It returns a [`java.net.URL`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html). Alternatively, you can use `getResourceAsStream(..)` to obtain the `InputStream` to the resource.